# Very Kind Neighbors

Tags: mathematics

a) Place numbers 1 to 25 on the cells of this board so that each of them, except for 1 and 2, is the sum of two of its (up to 8) neighbors in at least one way.

[image]

b) Do likewise with the numbers 1 to 36 in a 6 x 6 board? ¿Can a similar outcome be achieved in a square board of any larger size?

Puzzle due to Giulio Cesare.

Answer (score 2):

For a:

> ```
>  25 24 17 23 22
>  16  9 15  8 14
>  19  7  2  6 20
>  12  5  3  4 10
>  18 13  1 11 21
> ```

Or if each number must be doable in exactly one way:

> ```
>  25 24 15 23 20
>  16  9 17  6 14
>  19  7  2  4 10
>  12  5  3  1 21
>  18 13  8 11 22
> ```

For b:

> ```
>  32 33 18 26 19 31
>
>  21 11  1  7 12 29
>
>  34 10  4  3  9 17
>
>  24 16  6  2  5 25
>
>  30 14  8 13 15 20
>
>  36 22 27 23 28 35
> ```

(found via computer search.  Searching for a 7x7 found no solutions, even under the laxer "sum of two neighbors, in at least one way" rule)

Comment: So solutions for larger boards (say 8 x 8) not likely?

Answer (score 0):

a)

> [image]

b)

There's a 30 character minimum for a post